# How to make a simple up and down floating animation in SwitfUI?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I want to make the text "Hello, World!" float up and down, slowly, without stopping, once the view appears.

```
import SwiftUI

struct animate: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated: Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Here is possible simple approach. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4. Of course parameters can be tuned by needs.

[image: demo]

```
struct BoncingView: View {
    @State private var bouncing = false
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: bouncing ? .bottom : .top)
            .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 5.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: bouncing)
            .onAppear {
                self.bouncing.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there are for sure better and more elegant ways to solve it , but one way would be :

```
struct ContentView: View {


    @State var y : CGFloat = 100
    @State var addThis: CGFloat = 100


    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .position(x: 100, y: y)
            .onAppear() {
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
                    withAnimation() {
                        self.addThis = -self.addThis
                        self.y = self.y + self.addThis
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple floating animation on SwiftUI. I think it will be more correct use offset value for animation.

```
Text("HEY!")
    .offset(CGSize(width: 0, height: startAnimation ? -4 : 4))
    .animation(
        Animation.easeInOut(duration: 3).repeatForever(autoreverses: true),
        value: startAnimation
    )
    .onAppear {
        startAnimation.toggle()
    }
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541